# Time Interval in alamofire to watch for changes in an API

Tags: swift, swiftui, alamofire, combine

Can I use the time interval in Alamofire to reload an API for a set time of period? For example, I have an API which changes but does not publish the changes I have to call the `.get` request, again and again, to get new updates. Can `timeInterval` help in reloading the API to watch for changes? Which will only push update the array when there is an update

```
@Published var myArray = [MyModel]()

init() {
    fetchData()
}

func fetchData(){
    AF.request(myRouter.getData)
        .responseData{ (response) in
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
            let result: AFResult<[MyModel]> = decoder.decodeResponse(from: response)
            switch result {
            case let .success(value):
                self.myArray.append(contentsOf: value)
            case let .failure(error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to call `fetchData()` regularly at some interval - is this what you mean by "reload an API"?

Comment: Yes, but only update the view when there is new data. I tried by setting time it was reloading the view on the time I have set, which is not a got user experience.